# Spark skewed data optimisation

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am facing a big problem with my data and I need help. Here are the details of my problem:

I have two dataframes that I obtained after doing multiple joins. The first dataframe has 250k lines, and the second dataframe has 20 million lines.

My objective is to join these two dataframes to get a final table, but I am encountering issues. While I am able to display the data using Databricks, which shows the first 10K lines, I cannot count the dataframe and write it on the datalake. the job get blocked and start writing on disk(spill disk). I left it running for 4 hours without success.

I have tried multiple solutions such as broadcasting, salting, and dataframe repartitioning, but the problem persists.

**Cluster config :**
4 workers 32gb/worker | Driver with 32gb and 40 cores in total
I'm using pyspark on databricks.

I do not believe that the issue is related to resource constraints because I have monitored the cluster metrics and it did not exceed 40%. Additionally, I have enabled autoscaling on the cluster.

Here is a screenshot of spark_partition after repartition (**200**) in **DESC ORDER**

The first df (the little one)

[image]

The second dataframe with 20 million lines :

[image]

Here is a screenshot of id count after repartition (**200**) and salting  in **DESC ORDER**
The first df (the little one)

[image]

The second dataframe with 20 million lines :

[image]

Can anyone help me find a solution to this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This seems very vague. You basically simply say that something doesn't work because of data skew, that's all the information... The only thing I can say is: get a more powerful cluster.

Comment: Am I missing something? Taking the first `df` with 250k line of records, when you show that after the `repartition(200)` operation, the no. of counting in the top partitions is around 22k, which means the total number of records in your first `df` should be `22k*200~=4.4m`? Or it's still a highly skewed even after the repartitioning? Also, what's the number of column in both first and second dataframe?

Comment: You should provide the top cardinalities of the joined column instead of partitions sizer after repartition which is incorrect . only repartition by columns to be joined makes sense